# What is this error that comes up in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, warnings, jsctags

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](http://libraryinstitute.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/scoped-tags-support-for-javascript-in-vim/).

Then when I got to this part

```
node jsctags/bin/jsctags --sort=yes --locals tst.js
```

I got the following warning message.

> The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar
>   interface.

I'm doing this in OSX. First I tried the package and then I tried installing from source. I still get the same message.

What does this mean? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

In your `jsctags` file you probably have a line that looks like this:

```
sys = require ('sys');
```

As a first step, try using this line:

```
sys = require ('util');
```

This will still refer to the package by the name `sys` in your script, so the rest should work; but in the future, `util = require ('util');` might be better, to make it more clear that you're using the newer package and API.

Comment: I didn't find that in tst.js, I found it in jsctags. But even when I made the change, the message didn't go away.

Comment: Sorry, I blamed the wrong file. Check in `jsctags` instead. (Perhaps re-pull the `git` repository -- it might have been fixed upstream already.)

Answer (score 0):

The message is just Node's way of telling your sys module is deprecated and everyone should migrate to util.

The reason you're getting it may not be your fault. If any of the libraries you're using not migrated to the new modules, it'll also show that message.